# Avoid Ironruby from terminating itself after code executed

Tags: ironruby

I've written a very very very simple piece of code for Ironruby to check, if all works the way it should:

```
require "System.Windows.Forms"
include System::Windows::Forms
form = Form.new
form.Show
```

When I type this code directly into the interactive Ironruby console, it works as it should, but when I save this piece of code in a *test.rb* file and execute `ir test.rb` via command prompt, the Windows Form pops up and closes instantly after the whole code executed. **Is there a way to avoid this behavior?** I tried to use gets, but then the console was waiting for input, while the Form was frozen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The simple answer is just to change `form.Show` to `Application.Run form`

The reason your window closes instantly after the code is done requires understanding modal windows vs modeless windows. Here's a link for further reading: [Displaying Modal and Modeless Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Also here's an example of mixing modal and modeless:

```
require 'System.Drawing'
include System::Drawing
require 'System.Windows.Forms'
include System::Windows::Forms

class Dlg <Form
    def initialize
        self.Text = 'Modal'
        self.Load do
            self.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog

            showHide = Button.new
            showHide.Text = 'Show'
            self.Controls.Add(showHide)
            showHide.Click do
                if @modeless.nil?
                    @modeless = Form.new
                    @modeless.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
                    @modeless.Text = 'Modeless'
                    @modeless.FormClosing { @modeless = nil; showHide.Text = 'Show' }
                end
                if @modeless.Visible
                    @modeless.Hide # hide a modeless form
                    showHide.Text = 'Show'
                else
                    @modeless.Show # show a modeless form
                    showHide.Text = 'Hide'
                end
            end

            ok = Button.new
            ok.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
            ok.Text = 'OK'
            ok.Location = Point.new(0, showHide.Bottom+10)
            self.Controls.Add(ok)

            cancel = Button.new
            cancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
            cancel.Text = 'Cancel'
            cancel.Location = Point.new(ok.Right+10, ok.Top)
            self.Controls.Add(cancel)
        end
    end
end

dlg = Dlg.new
dlgResult = dlg.ShowDialog # show a modal dialog
if dlgResult != DialogResult.OK
    MessageBox.Show('NOT OK') # MessageBox.Show is modal
else
    MessageBox.Show('OK')
end
```

Comment: I forgot this problem, but thank you anyway. Currently I cannot test your answer, but I will test it (and give you feedback) :)